# Solving trigonometric equation in closed form

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve $x/sin(x) = a$ for $x$,  where $a$ is a constant. But I can't seem to find a closed form solution for it.

Comment: Similar answer:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317900/how-to-solve-x-sin-x-a-for-any-number-a Try numericaly: `sol[a_] := NSolve[x/Sin[x] == a && -2 Pi < x < 2 Pi, x, Reals]; sol[2]`

Comment: This does not seem to be a question specific to Mathematica.

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to the Kepler equation, which has no solutions in elemental functions

Answer (score 2):

The function contains poles where sin[x]==0. As the function is a periodic function, many solutions exist for x/sin[x]==a. So, one has to solve these kinds of problems numerically. Please follow @Mariusz Iwaniuk with appropriate bounds for x based on requirement.